# Basis for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,R)$ in terms of coordinate basis (or vice versa)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Given coordinates $(\varphi, U)$ near $e \in SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ we get a basis for $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{R})$ by pushing forward the basis for $T_{\varphi(p)} \hat{U}$ where $\hat{U} = \varphi(U) \subset \mathbb{R}^3$.

We also have a basis for $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2, \mathbb{R})$ given by:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, Y =  \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, Z = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} $$

If my choice of coordinate system is $\varphi:SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by:

$$ \varphi(\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\
c & \frac{1+bc}{a} \end{bmatrix})  = (a,b,c) $$

so that

$$ \varphi (\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} )  = (1,0,0) = \varphi(e) $$

how exactly would I go about computing the induced coordinate basis on $\mathfrak{sl}(2, \mathbb{R})$ in terms of $X,Y,Z$?

Comment: Just take differentiation w.r.t. $a,b,c$ to get the basis in terms of $2\times 2$ traceless matrices $\in \mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$. It is exactly how the Lie group is related to its Lie algebra.

Comment: Differentiation of what? Of $\varphi:SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R}^3$? Should I consider it as $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: You have a local coordinate chart given by $\phi$ (near the unit element of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Take differentiation in this coordinate. (which is exactly how we compute the pushforward of the differentials in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by $\phi^{-1}$)

Comment: $\varphi$ is a map defined on a manifold, when you say take differentiation do you mean compute its differential? $d\varphi_e: \mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{R}) \to T_{(1,0,0)} \mathbb{R}^3$? How would this get me in terms of 2x2 trace free matrices?

Comment: I mean the inverse $d\phi^{-1}$ from $T_{(1,0,0)}\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathfrak{sl}$. It doesn't even make sense to take differential w.r.t. $a,b,c$ along $\phi$.

Comment: $\varphi^{-1}(a,b,c)  = (a,b,c,\frac{1+bc}{a})$, so $d \varphi^{-1}_{(1,0,0)} (w): \{ v:C^{\infty}(SL(2, \mathbb{R}) \to \mathbb{R} \ \vert$ v a derivation $\}$ is defined by $d\varphi^{-1}_{(1,0,0)}(v)(f) = v(f \circ \varphi^{-1})$ . I am sure if I apply $d \varphi^{-1} $ to the standard ordered basis of $T_{(1,0,0)}\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}_{(1,0,0)}, \frac{\partial}{\partial y}_{(1,0,0)}, \frac{\partial}{\partial z}_{(1,0,0)} \}$ I will get a new basis for $\mathfrak{s}\mathfrak{l}(2,\mathbb{R})$, but how do I know what this is in terms of $X,Y,Z$?